# Merge Sort with Strings

Tags: java, string, mergesort

I have a linked list in a class named `WordNode`, which holds the following attributes:

```
String _word; WordNode _next;
```

I have another class which is the "actual list" which only holds a reference to the head of the list, the class is called `TextList` and it receives a `String` and supposed to put every word of the `String` SORTED IN THE LIST. For example, for the sentence:

```
coding in Java is cool.
```

The linked list would look like:

```
coding >>> cool >>> Java >>> in >>> is.
```

The arrows are like pointers to the next node in the list.

I want to first take all the words and put them in a linked list (`TextList` class) and then make a MERGE SORT to sort the words in the linked list.

What I though of doing is taking a split method to split the list into two lists: "odd" and "evens", which is these methods:

```
private TextList splitOdds(){
    boolean flag=true;
    TextList odds=new TextList();
    WordNode o=null;
    WordNode ptr=_head;
    while (ptr.getNext()!=null){
        if(flag)
            o=new WordNode(ptr.getWord(),o);
        ptr=ptr.getNext();
         flag=!flag;
    }
    odds._head=o;;
    return odds;
}

private TextList splitEvens(){
    boolean flag=true; 
    TextList evens=new TextList();
    WordNode e=null;
    WordNode ptr=this._head.getNext();
    while (ptr!=null){
        if(flag)
            e=new WordNode(ptr.getWord(),e);
        ptr=ptr.getNext();
        flag=!flag;
    }
    evens._head=e;
    return evens;
}
```

The split does work.

But I don't know where to continue from here. I want to call the split method, recursively and split the list until it is a list of one or two nodes, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Edit: can not use a third class, forhibited by the excercise. Also holding the length of TextList. Only holding number of times each word appears by an attribute on WordNode class.

Comment: Are you required to put all the elements into a list and *then* sort? Or are you allowed to insert the items in sorted order as you go? IMO, the later is preferable.

Comment: why don't you sort the words while inserting them in the list?

Comment: @Code-Guru, I am not required to insert and then sort or vice versa, but I thought that inserting and then sorting would be more efficient, even if more complicated.. OlayinkaSF, same for your question. Merge sort may give me O(nlogn) time complexity and inserting sorted can be O(n^2)

Comment: It depends on how you insert items. If you have to traverse the list to insert on the end each time, your overall algorithm of insert-then-sort will still be O(n^2), so you might as well insert the items in order.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the concept is wrong. You dont need to use merge-sort here. Try searching for PriorityQueue or actually BinaryHeap in order to solve this task. Secondly, merge sort on linked list is not a good idea since it will not be efficient at all. I think you should totally rework your solution.

NB. Just implement the operation YourLinkedList.getByIndex() for convinience, add the size atribute to hold the number of items in the linked list, then create one more linkedList and perform the bottom-up merge-sort like you would do with a simple array.

Structures:

```
public class Item {

    private String word;
    private Item next;

    public Item(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public Item getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Item next) {
        this.next = next;
    }
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

}
```

Linked List:

```
public class LinkedList {

    private int size = 0;
    private Item first = null;  

    public void swapFragment(LinkedList list, int from, int to) {
        if (from >= 0 && to < size) {
            list.get(to-from).setNext(this.get(to+1));          
            if (from > 0) {
                this.get(from-1).setNext(list.get(0));
            } else {
                this.first = list.get(0);
            }
        }       
    }   
    public void addItem(String word) {
        if (first == null) {
            first = new Item(word);
        } else {
            Item item = first;
            while (item.getNext() != null) {
                item = item.getNext();
            }   
            item.setNext(new Item(word));
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    public Item get(int index) {
        if (index >= size) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Item item = first;
            for(int i = 1; i <= index; i++) {
                item = item.getNext();
            }
            return item;
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public String toString() {
        Item item = first;
        String message = null;
        if (item != null) {
            message = item.getWord() + " ";
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        while (item.getNext() != null) {
            item = item.getNext();
            message = message + item.getWord() + " ";
        }
        return message;
    }


}
```

Merge Sort:

```
public class ListMergeSort {

    public void sort(LinkedList list, int lo, int hi) {
        if (hi <= lo) {
            return;
        }
        int mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2;
        sort(list, lo, mid);
        sort(list, mid+1, hi);      
        merge(list, lo, hi, mid);       
    }

    private void merge(LinkedList list, int lo, int hi, int mid) {
        int i = lo;
        int j = mid+1;
        LinkedList newList = new LinkedList();
        for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
            if (i > mid) {
                newList.addItem(list.get(j).getWord());
                j++;
            } else if (j > hi) {
                newList.addItem(list.get(i).getWord());
                i++;
            } else if (list.get(i).getWord().compareTo(list.get(j).getWord()) < 0) {
                newList.addItem(list.get(i).getWord());
                i++;
            } else {
                newList.addItem(list.get(j).getWord());
                j++;
            }           
        }
        list.swapFragment(newList, lo, hi);
    }

}
```

Test Class for Strings:

```
import org.junit.*;

public class MergeTest {

    @Test
    public void testWords() {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        list.addItem("word");
        list.addItem("pipe");
        list.addItem("trainer");
        list.addItem("stark");
        list.addItem("33");
        list.addItem("dmitry");
        ListMergeSort lms = new ListMergeSort();
        lms.sort(list, 0, list.getSize()-1);        
    }

}
```

Now you just need to create a class which receives a string as an argument, splits it with String.split() and adds the resulting words into the internal LinkedList datastructure. Then you sort them inside with the merge sort and you get the result.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I don't have a choice here, it's an excercise for home work.

Comment: Well, this does not solve the OP's problem, so this should not be an answer, this should be posted as a comment

Answer (score 0):

This is of course assuming that you keep the length of the list at each insertion or deletion. All you have to do is split the list in half like this while keeping the head/root of the original list. You will not even need any intermediary list while implementing your merge sort.

```
    LinkedList LinkedList::split(){
            _Node_* p=head, *q=p;
            for(int i=0; i<len/2; i++){
                    q=p;
                    p=p->next;
            }
            LinkedList ret;
            ret.head=p;
            ret.len=len-len/2;
            len=len/2;
            q->next=NULL;
            return ret;
    }
```